# How can I cast a float numpy array value to an int inside of a numba jitted function in nopython mode

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Inside a numba jitted nopython function, I need to index an array with the values inside of an another array. Both arrays are numpy arrays floats.

For example

```
@numba.jit("void(f8[:], f8[:], f8[:])", nopython=True)
def need_a_cast(sources, indices, destinations):
    for i in range(indices.size):
        destinations[i] = sources[indices[i]]
```

My code is different, but let's assume the problem is reproducible by this stupid example (i.e., I cannot have indices of type int). AFAIK, i cannot use int(indices[i]) nor indices[i].astype("int") inside of nopython jit function.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using numba 0.24 at least, you can do a simple cast:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def need_a_cast(sources, indices, destinations):
    for i in range(indices.size):
        destinations[i] = sources[int(indices[i])]

sources = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float64)
indices = np.arange(10, dtype=np.float64)
np.random.shuffle(indices)
destinations = np.empty_like(sources)

print indices
need_a_cast(sources, indices, destinations)
print destinations

# Result
# [ 3.  2.  8.  1.  5.  6.  9.  4.  0.  7.]
# [ 3.  2.  8.  1.  5.  6.  9.  4.  0.  7.]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really cannot use `int(indices[i])` (it works for JoshAdel and also for me) you should be able to work around it with `math.trunc` or `math.floor`:

```
import math

...

destinations[i] = sources[math.trunc(indices[i])] # truncate (py2 and py3)
destinations[i] = sources[math.floor(indices[i])] # round down (only py3)
```

`math.floor` works only for Python3 as far as I know because it returns a `float` in Python2. But `math.trunc` on the other hand rounds up for negative values.